# RichFaces to PrimeFaces migration

Tags: primefaces, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I am migrating my entire application built on RichFaces to PrimeFaces
There are few components of RichFaces which are not available in PrimeFaces and I am not able to find its exact counter part. These are the below components I am stuck with.

1) `<a4j:queue ignoreDupResponses="true"/>`
We have a global template.xhtml file where we this attribute defined. this template.xhtml has CSS files, methods for form submit, checking for serialization of forms etc. This template is imported in all the other xhtml files. Is there a PrimeFaces counter part to ignoredupresponses of a4j?

2) what are the primefaces counter parts for `<rich:notifyStack>` and `<rich:notifyMessages>`?

Comment: 1: what does it solve for you? Look for a PF/JSF solution for the problem, not a 1:1 replacement of the tag) 2: Same, we don't know what they do, so describe what you want functional wise and we can suggest solutions

Comment: It ignores duplicate ajax responses. We have p:ajax async="false" for this, but this needs to be put down on individual pages where we have ajax calls. the a4j:queue ignoreDupResponses is put in a global template.xhtml file which is included in all the other pages.

Comment: I know what it technically does, but what FUNCTIONAL issue does it solve for you? And why should a duplicate (100% identical?) response occur?

Comment: So a `p:ajax async="false"` solves your functional issue? But iirc, that is the default...!